# How to properly make jar archive to run Java program on different systems?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I have this, perhaps, easy problem, but I don't know how to handle this.
I have my Java program and it works pretty well when I call it via terminal (Java command).

The program uses 4 text files from the hard disk which can't be added as resources to the project.

How to do this right so I could build jar file only with main class and files from hard disk (first one is a config file and it has paths to other files so the program knows where they are)?

I'm using `IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 on Arch Linux`.

I did it based on [this blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/), but it's not working without txt files in `src` folder.
Also "`jar cvf`" command builds jar file, but it's not working outside my computer (for example on windows or OSX).

Can anyone help me?
I prefer step by step instruction so I would understand what is going on in here.

Comment: Who does provide the initial text files? The developer or is it already available somewhere in the OS/ on the harddisk?

Comment: They are on the hdd so user can edit them using simple text files editor.
Most important is config.txt which stores paths to other files on hdd, and this one has to be in same catalog which app (.jar file?).

Comment: And this config.txt file is already there before you install the application, but the application has to be installed in the same directory?

Comment: For now config.txt is required by app so it knows how and where to handle other files and also user needs easy access to this files so he or she could modify this. So this has to be only just before execution
I know I could do this in app, but for now it only has console mode and I will add graphical interface in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to build your application with Maven and create a [Maven Assembly](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) which contains your JAR file as well as the config.txt file.

Comment: Thank you.
Do you have tutorial how to make this as it should be done?

Comment: The mentioned Maven Site for Maven Assembly also provides examples, http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/index.html, eg. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html

Comment: You might want to use the format "zip" instead of "jar" as in the example.

Comment: The most important thing is to make this work on OS X or Windows. Format doesn't matter.